# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/moviedata.json'

Tags: javascript, json

im working in node Js.
When im trying to load a file: moviedata.json, with this lines:

```
var allMovies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8'));
```

Shows:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './moviedata.json'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
>       at Object. (/Users/dortiz/Documents/NodeJS/pruebas/zw/aws/MoviesLoadData.js:13:31)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'moviedata.json'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
>       at Object. (/Users/dortiz/Documents/NodeJS/pruebas/zw/aws/MoviesLoadData.js:13:31)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)

The file to read its in same folder that js.

[image]

But im don't understand what im doing wrong

Comment: fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8') will look for file in same folder location

Comment: `__dirname + '/moviedata.json'`

Comment: With __dirname its working thanks

Comment: You have to puth the correct path

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8')` will look for `moviedata.json` in the directory from where you ran your application, not in the directory where your `MoviesLoadData.js` file is located.

Suppose you ran `node aws/MoviesLoadData.js` from `/Users/dortiz/Documents/NodeJS/pruebas/zw`,  `fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8')` would look for `moviedata.json` in `/Users/dortiz/Documents/NodeJS/pruebas/zw`, not in `/Users/dortiz/Documents/NodeJS/pruebas/zw/aws`

If you were to run your script with my given example, you'd need to prepend the path to the json file to correctly reference it.

```
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/moviedata.json', 'utf8')
```

I'm not sure how you run your code, so my example may not work in your codebase, but hopefully understanding where you went wrong will help debug your code.